# Google Places Javascript Api photo redirects to photo url but returns 403

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, google-api-javascript-client

I have an issue with showing photos from the Google Places (Javascript) API. I follow the instructions for getting a photo and it's url with .getUrl(). This returns a url that looks like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PhotoService.GetPhoto?XXX&2e1&callback=none&key=XXX&token=XXX
```

This immediately redirects (302) the user to a URL that looks something like:

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNsemCsJsmheK-edlzYPxkd5dQRGjQeRcmr7VDy=s1600-w600
```

When I use this in my page, it works perfectly for a few requests, but later in the day, it returns a 403 (however if I paste the URL in the browser, it shows the image just fine). Looks like a quota issue, but I'm breaking my head, since I'm a premium user and quota shouldn't be an issue on any of the API's (especially not after say 20 requests).

The only thing I keep finding is [this information from Google](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) that says a 403 can be returned if quota is reached, but it doesn't look the same, and I would expect that 403 to arise before the 302 redirect. Again, I always get the redirected URL just fine.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: "When I use this in my page" care to show this? The fact that it works when you paste it the address bar but not in your code, points at an issue with your code. From  https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits "a HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error. In most cases, this is due to an invalid URL signature" Also, "If too many requests are made within a certain time period, the API returns an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response code" https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm using Angular, but I'm doing nothing special with the url, just use it as an image src:
<img [src]="photoUrl"/>

Comment: Interesting, is the link now broken for you? I just used it in an existing angular project of mine and it is working when using the url directly in an `img` tag.

Comment: The funny thing is it works for a while and after some time the urls (a fresh one every time) stop working :/

Comment: The one in my original post still works in an angular project by the way, and keeps working if I use it directly (but of course in the real life situation I wouldn't have it). I've also tried a different approach by trying to get the redirected URL using a http request to the first url and then reading the redirected URL, however the endpoint doesn't allow this due to CORS limitations.

Comment: Have the same problem. Some images work, some don’t. If I paste the url in the browser, it loads. If after that I refresh my page, the image shows fine! Do we have to await the getUrl or follow the url before using it as omg src?